# "Undefined is not a constructor" error in tests when using jQuery in combination with Angular

Tags: jquery, angularjs, npm, gulp, karma-runner

I'm getting `TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'expect(element).toContainElement('#zipCode')')` when using jQuery in combination with Angular. The research I've done made me come to the conclusion that jQuery overrides `angular.element`. I use **PhantomJS 2.x**.

My gulp pipeline uses `wiredep`. By default, it excludes jQuery. When I run my tests with jQuery excluded, one of my bower dependencies complains about not being able to find jQuery. When I tell `wiredep` to NOT exclude jQuery, I get the above error.

I'm looking for a general direction as to what I should do next. The dependency that's causing this error is not necessary for the test, but may be necessary in the future for certain tests.

**The test:**

```
it('creates a postalcode input field', function () {
  var element = $compile('<postcode></postcode>')($rootScope);
  $rootScope.$digest();
  expect(element).toContainElement('#zipCode');
});
```

Comment: It could be the order the javascript files are loaded: when jQuery is included it must be loaded before angular, but as angular doesn't require jQuery there won't be a dependency in the bower files to force that order.

Comment: Perhaps overwriting the $ ? try $.noConflict(); https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/